Hottest point of a convex area of the plane
Consider 2d transient heat conduction inside a convex area of the plane A. So we have
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} $$
Initially, all of A is at a high temperature of 100C. At t=0, the boundary condition of T = 0 is applied on the boundary of A. As A cools, the contour T(x,y,t) = 0 moves from the boundary of A into the interior of A, until eventually T = 0 everywhere.
I would like to know if :

The hot region enclosed by the contour T(x,y,t) = 0 is always convex.

At any time t, does the hottest point have a simple gemetrical characterization ? For example, is the hottest point the centroid of A for all t? Or does it vary spatially in time ?


If A is not convex, it is easy to see that both (1) and (2) are false.

Does the contour $T(x,y,t) = 0$ necessarily move at all, or is it possible (at least for some convex $A$) that $T > 0$ on the interior of $A$ for all time? To put it another way, is question (1) really about some kind of analysis of the regions $T(x,y,t) = \epsilon$, for $0 < \epsilon < 100$ perhaps taken to be near $0$?

There is a difference between a boundary condition- imposed on $\partial R$ for all $t$ (were $R$ is the region in which you solve the pde), and an initial condition $T(x,y,0)$. If your boundary condition is $T_{\partial R}=0$ then that contour stays there forever. If you mean an initial condition with a contour of $T=0$ somewhere, then you need to state $R$ and also the boundary conditions

To clarify, the intial condition is $T(x,y,0) = 100$ and the boundary condition is $T_{\partial R} =0.$ For any $t > 0$,  there is a whole region between $\partial R$ and an inner contour where T =0. This inner contour is what I was referring to.

In this case, all points in within the area have $T(x,y,t)>0$ for all $t$, so there is no inner contour

Not sure I understand your comment @Sal. Which case ? Which area ? To reiterate, at any time t > 0, the region $R$ is divded into two by an inner contour given by $T(x,y,t) = 0$. The region between this inner contour and $\partial R$ has $T(x,y,t) = 0$ everywhere. The region inside this inner contour has $T(x,y,t) => 0$.

I mean: the area $R$ has everywhere $0<T<100$ for $t>0$ except along $\partial R$. You suppose that $R$ is divided into two by an inner contour- this is not true because there can be no inner contour
